# Applying sliderValues to inputted file

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to connect slider values in my app to the table, rendered from an uploaded file, though I can't understand how to do that properly. Here is how the code looks right now:

server.r

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output) {

  # upload the csv file

  output$contents <- renderTable({

    inputFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inputFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inputFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=',',
             quote="'")
  })

  # Create a frame with our values

  sliderValues <- reactive({

    # Compose data frame
    data.frame(
      Name = c("cost", 
               "range"),
               Value = as.character(c(input$cost, 
                                      paste(input$range, collapse=' ')
               ), 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    )
  }) 

  # Show the values
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
}
```

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Cars plot"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                '.csv')),
      helpText("Note: svc file should be separated by comas, and contain ",
               "single quotes only."),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      tags$hr(),
        sliderInput("cost", "Max cost:",
                    min=0, max=1000000, value=500000, pre = "$"),
        sliderInput("range", "Range of MaxSpeed:",
                    min = 50, max = 500, value = c(100,450))
        ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents'),
      tableOutput('values')
    )
  )
)
```

finally, the file i'm using to test it looks like this:

```
Car, Horsepower, MaxSpeed, Cost
AlfaRomeo, 200, 300, 200000
AstonMartin, 400, 310, 300000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost done. Just assign your `dataframe` and `subset` with `input` values:

```
mytable<-read.csv(inputFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=',',
         quote="'")

subset(mytable,mytable$Cost<input$cost & mytable$MaxSpeed>=input$range[1] & mytable$MaxSpeed<=input$range[2] )
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for. I had no idea about `subset`, today is my first day of learning.